# 'Manual' bulk image uploads to MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

Is there some way to skip the file upload dialog, which is really tiresome if you have lots of uploads?

I have direct access to the server and can upload files directly, outside MediaWiki. However, if I point directly to a file I've already uploaded:

```
[[Media:/path/to/file1.png|file 1]]
[[File:/path/to/file2.png|file 2]]
```

then I just get taken to the file upload dialog, instead of linking to the existing image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're [different ways](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Bulk_upload) on how to do that, and it depends on what you actually want:
* A one time solution to import images you've from somewhere else
* Provide a general way for your users to bulk upload images

For your use case, and as you explicitly mention that you've direct access to the server, I would suggest to use the [`importImages.php` maintenance script](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:ImportImages.php). This script needs to be run on the same server as your MediaWiki installation is located in, e.g. with:

```
php maintenance/importImages.php /path/to/images/directory
```

You can find more information about the usage on the linked documentation page.

Answer (score 0):

The [MsUpload extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MsUpload) allows users to upload multiple files by drag & drop in the standard MediaWiki edit page.